# Pair up strings to form palindromes

Tags: algorithm

Given N strings each of at max 1000 length. We can concatenate pair of strings by ends. Like if one is "abc" and other is "cba" then we can get "abccba" as well as "cbaabc". Some string may be left without concatenation to any other string. Also no string can be concatenated to itself.

**We can only concatenate those two strings that form a palindrome. So I need to tell the minimum number of strings left after making such pairs.**

**Example** : Let we have 9 strings :

```
aabbaabb 
bbaabbaa
aa
bb
a
bbaa
bba
bab
ab
```

Then here answer is 5

**Explanation** : Here are 5 strings :

```
"aabbaabb" + "bbaabbaa" = "aabbaabbbbaabbaa"
"aa" + "a = "aaa"
"bba" + "bb" = "bbabb"
"bab" + "ab" = "babab"
"bbaa"
```

Also there can be 1000 such strings in total.

Comment: Sounds like a fun problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @reto There are some observations that i had noticed. First if a string is a palindrome than we can add other palindrome to it.If its not we need to string of this type : {Palindrome} + {remaining characters to make first string palindrome}

Comment: @reto Main problem lies in fact that suppose we pair up some string like this but there may be some better pairing that pair up a left alone string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Make a graph where we have one node for each word.

2) Go through all pairs of words and check if they form palindrome if we concatenate them. If they do connect corresponding nodes in graph with edge.

3) Now use matching algorithm to find maximum number of edges you can match: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm

Time complexity: O(N) for point 1, O(n*n*1000) for point 2 and O(V^4) for point 3 yielding total complexity of O(n^4).

Comment: Maximum number of edges in what sense ? You are matching what to what ?

Comment: What about left over nodes ? As many nodes may not get paired with anyone

Comment: Also you are assuming graph as directed right ? Also edmond run in O(V^3) How are you saying it as O(E*sqrt(V) ?

Comment: You want to take maximum number of edges in graph, so that no two selected edges have common node.

Comment: where n can go to 1000 ?

Comment: If n can go up to 1000, than my algorithm will have to be improved. We are looking for O(n*n*lg(n)) algorithm at worst than. However I still believe that my approach is the only way to solve problem like this.